# Why do I get this error, LabelEncoder?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm trying to fit the values from `numberOne` and `numberTwo` so that it fits with `LabelEncoder`, which I'll later use to `train_test_split` the data. However I get the following error:

> `'bad input shape ()' It seems that the problem is on line le.fit(X)`

My code:

```
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder

numberOne = 9
numberTwo = 1

X = numberOne
y = numberTwo

le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
le.fit(X)
X = le.transform
print X

le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
le.fit(y)
y = le.transform
print y
```

Comment: I don't know much about scikit, but I'm guessing `fit` is supposed to take a list. You're giving it an integer.

Answer (score 1):

As @Kevin said in the comment, `fit` takes lists as input, or preferably NumPy arrays, not scalars.